# Ubuntu 19.04: unable to hide Activities screen

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, activities-overview

When I press <kbd>Super</kbd> Key, I get to see the Activities screen and then I try to press <kbd>escape</kbd> to hide the Activities screen but nothing happens.

I had to either shut down or log out to remove the Activities screen.

Comment: How do we know the user is using the gnome extension workspace grid? Removing that extension is the solution in the duplicate question, yet I do not see indication here that that extension is being used.